# How to mearsure the average cpu frequency in linux?

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, electrical-power, frequency

I'm trying to measure the average cpu frequency in an DVFS enabled cpu for specific
interval , the obvious way of periodically sampling /proc/cpuinfo has
very large variants. The cpufreq-stats driver gave me some hope ,e.g.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state 
2600000 118148
2000000 8562
1600000 11041
1200000 3428602    # lots of ticks is idle ticks
```

but unfortunately it is mixed with idle ticks(see patch ["Do not account for idle time when tracking
time_in_state"](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/72488/)).  During idle time it is  probable that cpu will fall back to the lowest frequency ,thus skew the frequency distribution significantly .

The patch above utilize the account_idle_tick function to remove the idle
ticks from statics, but it seems only works for xen kernel.  Is there alternative way to measure average cpu frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new development version [Sysstat 9.1.6](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/changelog.html) includes a new option (-m FREQ) to report average cpu frequency ,e.g.

```
$ sar -m FREQ -P ALL 0
Linux 2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.i686.PAE (palmer.localdomain)     10/23/2010     _i686_        (2 CPU)

02:36:09 PM     CPU   wghMHz
02:36:09 PM     all   1042.23
02:36:09 PM       0   1039.43
02:36:09 PM       1   1166.65
```

The average weight is the time spent in that frequency , for example in a 10 second reporting interval , first 8 seconds the frequency is in 1GHz, the last 2 seconds is in 2GHz, then the average frequency 1.2 GHz

Answer (score 0):

perhaps `sar` is what you are looking for. As of release 9.0.0 of `sysstat`, `sar` can collect the cpu frequency. From `man sar`:

```
-m     Report  power management statistics.  Note that these statistics
       depend on sadc option "-S POWER" to be collected.  The following
       value is displayed:

       MHz
         CPU clock frequency in MHz.
```

Comment: Hi Christian , I've checked the sysstat(9.0+) source code, it turns out that sysstat simply periodically check /proc/cpuinfo for the "MHz" line. So its reading is not very useful to me . Thanks anyway